# How to change the color of a specific digit in a string of digits

Tags: excel, vba

The cells I am working with all contain strings of nine-digit numbers (no zeros), in random order. I would like to assign a different color to each individual digit. For example all "ones" should be red, all the "twos" should be blue, etc...
I tried the following which works fine with letters, but I cannot find a way to make it work for digits (1 to 9:

```
Sub ChangeCellCharacterColors()
Dim cell As Range, i As Integer, cellVal As String
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells 'Enter sheet name and range of cells to iterate through
cellVal = cell.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(cellVal)
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "B" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 4 'Identify character "B" and color index 4(green)
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "D" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "F" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "H" Then cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 5
    Next i
Next cell
End Sub
```

Could someone advise me how to change this code (or create a new one) for my purpose?

Comment: First save the number as text and not a number then when you compare the number make sure it is in quotes: `If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = "1"`

Comment: Note that you must store numbers as text for this to work.